# why is the global keyword not needed with an object

Tags: python, global-variables, global

in this example i need to include the global keyword. I have read elsewhere on stack exchange that immutable objects need the global keyword.

```
def foo(param):
    global message
    message += param

message = " hello "

foo("world")

print(message)
```

but in this example using lists which are mutable i *also* need the global keyword.

```
def foo(param):
    global message
    message += [ param ]

message = [ "hello" ]

foo("world")

print(message)
```

but in this example I create a 'container' object which allows me to fore go the global keyword.

```
class container:

    def __init__(self):
        self._message = ""

    def __str__(self):
        return self._message

    def add(self, param):
        self._message += param

def foo(param):
    message.add(param)

message = container()
message.add(" hello ")

foo("world")

print(message)
```

What are the rules for using the global keyword? This seems inconsistent

Comment: In your second example, if you were to use an object method like ``list.append``, you would not need the ``global`` keyword. Rule-of-thumb: whenever the assignment operator (``=, -=, +=``) operator is involved, you need the ``global`` keyword, otherwise the assignment limits the variable to the current scope.

Comment: There are two things you might want to do with a global name: 1) change what the name actually refers to, and 2) modify the object pointed to by the name. Mutability is only an issue insofar as with a global name pointing to an immutable object, one is the only thing you *can* do, which requires the `global` statement. If the global name refers to a mutable object, you need `global` for 1), but not for 2).

Answer (score 0):

This [frequently asked question](https://docs.python.org/3.6/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#id9) has an answer in the official documentation:

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was required for all global references, you’d be using global all the time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying side-effects.

See also the [documentation on `global`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) for more details.